# DOJO base/Fx has no animateProperty method

Tags: javascript, dojo, jsfiddle

I'm trying to animate the transparency change if a  element using dojo/_base/fx animateProperty(). However I hit an error on console saying **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'animateProperty' **. Not able to figure out what's wrong with the code. Here's the fiddle I created for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/kLMZC/2/

Posting code snippet too:

```
require(["dojo/fx", "dojox/fx/scroll", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!","dojo/window","dojo/dom-geometry","dojo/dom-style", "dojo/_base/fx"],
    function(coreFx, easing, dom, style, on, win, domGeometry, fx){
        on(dom.byId("contactFormButton1"), "click", function(){
            //dojo.byId('screen1').style.opacity = '0.5';
            fx.animateProperty({
                 node: dom.byId("screen1"), duration: 5000,
                 properties: {
                 opacity: { start: '1', end: '0.5' }
                 }
            }).play();


            style.set("screen2", "display", "block");
            dojo.byId('contactFormButton1').style.display = 'none';
            dojox.fx.smoothScroll({
                node: dojo.byId('screen2'),
                win: window
            }).play();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require([
    "dojo/fx", "dojox/fx/scroll",
    "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!",
    "dojo/window", "dojo/dom-geometry", "dojo/_base/fx"
], function (coreFx, easing, dom, style, on, ready, win, domGeometry, fx) {
    on(dom.byId("contactFormButton1"), "click", function () {
        //dojo.byId('screen1').style.opacity = '0.5';
        fx.animateProperty({
            node: dom.byId("screen1"),
            duration: 5000,
            properties: {
                 opacity: {
                     start: '1',
                     end: '0.5'
                 }
             }
         }).play();

        dojo.byId('contactFormButton1').style.display = 'none';

    });
});
```

The problem is a mismatch between the `require` and function parameters. You forgot `ready` as parameter.

http://jsfiddle.net/kLMZC/2/

Comment: Is there a reason why you're adding `dojo/_base/fx` to a second `require()` block?

Comment: It was for readability, but ofcourse not necessary. The real problem of the OP was that he forgot to put `ready` as function parameter. Therefore, fx wasn't defined. He can also replace his `require` with mine and it will work: `require(["dojo/fx", "dojox/fx/scroll", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/window", "dojo/dom-geometry", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/_base/fx"],

function (coreFx, easing, dom, style, on, ready, win, domGeometry, style, fx) {...` See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLMZC/2/

Comment: Fit in perfectly! Thanks a lot GuyT! :)

Comment: You've also placed a double `style` ;) Check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLMZC/3/